# Why is power so often associated with current and not also voltage?

Tags: voltage, power, current

I was reading one of my textbooks the other day about linear BJT emitter-follower amplifiers (non-relevant) and came across the following passage:

> Although the small-signal voltage gain of the emitter follower is slightly less than 1, the small signal current gain is normally greater than 1. Therefore the emitter follower circuit produces a small signal power gain.

But I've learned that the power can be expressed:

\$P = IR = \frac{V^2}{R} = I^2R\$

Which means that power is directly proportional to both current AND voltage. Wouldn't this mean that a large voltage gain also provides a power gain?

This is not the only place I've seen this discrepancy either. It seems that whenever people talk about power, they are only really concerned with current and not voltage, even though the math seems to suggest that is not the case.

Can anyone elaborate on this?

EDIT: One explanation I can think of is that there can be voltage across an open circuit, so increasing that voltage would theoretically increase power, even though nothing is getting hot... whereas if there's current flow increasing power by increasing current would make the component dissipate more energy...

Comment: Nothing in the passage you quoted contradicts what you said. Can you explain your confusion?

Comment: I'm just confused as to why they (the authors) would mention that right then. They just finished explaining all about common-emitter amplifiers and their high voltage-gain characteristic, but didn't mention power gain once. It seems to imply that voltage (of the two, current and voltage) is the less-associated with power.

Comment: I think you have the correct idea and *"people that are only concerned with current and not voltage"* probably assume that the **voltage is constant**, this might be the case in an amplifier which is powered from a certain constant power supply voltage. Note that to be able to increase the current, some impedance (R) has to be lowered !

Comment: The voltage gain is less than one, so it's a slight drop in power. However the current gain is greater than one, so this offsets that drop and adds a little more power.

Comment: @FakeMoustache And the emitter-follower accomplishes this by having an output impedance far lower than the input impedance?

Comment: @RogerRowland Hmm, so perhaps, they are talking about a net power gain, implying that in, say, a common-emitter amplifier, the current gain cancels out the voltage gain?

Comment: Yes, it would probably be more intuitive if they'd put some numbers on those gains. Maybe voltage gain is 0.95 and current gain is 50, for example.

Comment: The output impedance of the emitter follower is indeed lower **but that is not so relevant here**, the output power is not dissipated in that output impedance but in the load ! And the load can be much lower impedance because the e-follower can provide more current. Say you have a source which can only supply a signal of 1 mA, now add an e-follower with a beta of 100, at its output it can now supply a signal of 100 mA. Since an e-follower has a voltage gain close to 1, the available power at the output is almost a 100 times larger !

Comment: Ahhh, so I suppose they were just highlighting the fact that the emitter-follower could be used to bolster your signal's current to help drive whatever your feeding it into?

Comment: Yes, to help drive a low impedance load. Like in audio amplifiers, the last stage is often an e-follower to be able to drive the very low impedance of a loudspeaker (4 or 8 ohms). The stages before that last e-follower stage take care of the voltage gain and some current gain, the last stage only does current gain.

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Comment: Current is more relevant since power in is determined by constant voltage input times variable current loads when output is rail to rail or saturated near the rail with a voltage drop then both are important.

Comment: oh ok, so you're getting out a slightly diminished voltage signal with more current thus more power, I see, thanks

Comment: $$ P = VI  = \frac{V^2}{R} = I^2R$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that whenever people talk about power, they are only really
>   concerned with current and not voltage

Ignorant people perhaps, but every competent electrical engineer knows that *both* voltage and current must be taken into account.

> **Although** the small-signal voltage gain of the emitter follower is
>   slightly less than 1, the small signal current gain is normally
>   greater than 1.

There is no discrepancy here. The authors are pointing out that *if* there is current gain *then* voltage gain is not required to increase power. So the myth they are trying to dispel is that you can't have power gain without **voltage** gain - exactly the opposite of what you think people are concerned about.

> One explanation I can think of is that there can be voltage across an
>   open circuit, so increasing that voltage would theoretically increase
>   power

If the output is open circuit then it will draw no current so there cannot be any power gain. However it may still be useful to consider the voltage gain if that voltage can be maintained with a load.

In some circuits (eg. video amplifier) the source and load impedances are matched, resulting in half of the output voltage and power being lost in the source. In this case you would normally only consider the voltage gain under load (so a video amp with open circuit voltage gain of 2 is actually a unity gain buffer).

In others (eg. audio amplifier) the load impedance is normally much higher than the source impedance, so the voltage gain remains (almost) constant whether driving the load or open circuit. If the load impedance is reduced then it will draw more current and power at the same voltage. This is not important for low level signals so usually only the voltage is considered. The output power of an audio power amplifier is very important, so speaker impedance is *always* considered - but output voltage and current are rarely mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that power is a function of both current and voltage.

There are circumstances where one is more significant than the other. Using the quoted example of an emitter follower (aka common collector) amplifier, the voltage gain is almost 1 (not very interesting) so all the power gain comes from the current gain.

But wire the same transistor as a common base amplifier - the input is supplied to the emitter. Now most of the current appears at the collector (i.e. the current gain is almost 1; you lose a tiny fraction to the base) so all the power gain comes from voltage gain.

And of course the common emitter has both voltage and current gain, hence relatively high power gain.

---

However there are cases where power is most usefully expressed as I^2R - often wasted power in a motor or a long cable.

Consider a transmission line supplying voltage V and current I to another city. The power wasted in transmission is independent of V, and proportional to I^2.

Now, associating wasted power with current is useful; we can see that to minimise waste, we want to reduce current. So to transmit the same power we want to increase voltage. Which is why high voltage transmission lines are used, despite the expense of transformers at either end.

Naturally the power transmitted to the load is VL * I (where VL is measured at the load end), while the power required is VG * I (where VG is measured at the generator) - and the difference (VG - VL) is the voltage drop along the cable = I * R.

A similar case is seen in electric motors, where the main power loss is I^2R losses in the winding resistance R. There is no similar loss due to voltage, so it follows that a motor is most efficient run at relatively high speed (speed is proportional to voltage) and relatively low torque load (torque is proportional to current).

In both these cases, and perhaps others, thinking about wasted power in terms mainly of current leads to useful insights.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered your question in the "edit" part.

It's right, \$P = VI\$, but in the equation you wrote, \$P = IR = \frac{V^2}{R} = I^2R\$, is more evident that there's also a resistance that play in the game.

Power is the work done in the unit of time, or better is the amount of **energy consumed** per unit time.
Voltage is **potential energy**, and I can have a big voltage source, but if we don't put a resistor across the source, the energy remain "potential", don't do any job.
When we connect a load a current flow and "do something".

But... you have already written this in more succinct way, in the "EDIT". :-)

Comment: I didn't even think about my edit that way, in terms of types of energy, that's a good point. When writing it I forgot the fact that an open circuit means no current, or infinite resistance, which means no power delivered, as Bruce Abbott pointed out above. I'm still getting used to the load vs. source resistance concept however-- thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Although voltage can/does vary, many things are designed for a fixed voltage, so to change power you change the current.  The AC power coming out of the wall, sure that is AC, but its amplitude and frequency are fixed, it is current that is tied to power assuming V fixed.  A battery based system although the voltage can vary it is the current that does most of the changing.  Just about everything is designed around a fixed-ish voltage, and current varies, so if you hold V constant then P is related to I and you normally only need to talk about I.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be because power is directly proportional to both current AND voltage **drop** (not just "voltage", in the sense of voltage to ground).  Power dissipated at any device is \$P=I \Delta V\$, where \$V\$ is the voltage drop across terminals.  When you look at different devices in series in a given circuit section, each voltage drop may vary a lot, but the current is common to all of them. In this situation, current helps better to get a handle on power.

See also [this other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/255566/the-relation-of-power-heat-losses-with-v-i-in-transmission-lines).